# Javascript dynamic property with value of array is empty after push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic3

This is crazy. I'm reading in an object from a webserver and looping through it, and I can add properties to the object. But when I try and make a new map on my own it doesn't work. As simple as I can make it

```
// from the server and works
plans: any[];
sourceByPlan: any[];

// my own map for other purposes I try to fill
// as I loop through the items from the server
customMap: any[]; // also tried 'any'

var res = JSON.parse(response);
this.plans = res.plans; // where res.plans looks like [{value: "id", label: "readableid"}, {value: "id2", label: "otherreadable"}]
this.sourceByPlan = res.sources; // where res.sources looks like { id: [Object, Object, Object...]};

// loop through each source and add a property
for(var i = 0; i < this.plans.length; i++){
    if(this.sourceByPlan[this.plans[i].value]){
        for (var j = 0; j < this.sourceByPlan[this.plans[i].value].length; j++){
            var sObj = this.sourceByPlan[this.plans[i].value][j];

            var status = this.getStatus(sObj); // simple string
            sObj["newstatus"] = status; // THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED


            // here is where the new non working code starts
            var key = this.plans[i].value + status ; // looks like 'asdf1234pending'

            if (!customMap[key]) {
                customMap[key] = [];
            }

             customMap[key].push(sObj); // this will still be empty
        }   
    }
}
```

sObj does not come with the property sObj.newstatus from the server but it lets me add it as desired. I'm trying to build another map on the fly but every time I check console.log(customMap) it's empty every time. Logically it looks the same as the object I'm getting from the server.

Comment: What is `obj`?  I don't see any other references to it. Is that supposed to be `sObj`?

Comment: yes, I will edit that

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing a undefined object to your custom map. You probably want to use sObj:

```
customMap[key].push(sObj);
```

Comment: For an issue that is a simple typo, this should be a comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus why do you think so?

Comment: Because the problem was a simple typo and that is actually one of the reasons we have for closing questions. As you can see @Pointy did the right thing. That is our general way of handling issues like this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Will do next time! Will leave my answer here for other people to learn this as well

Comment: Actually, it would be best for you to delete your answer. Not everyone reads the comments and the best way to avoid others doing the same thing is to not have examples of it being done. ;)

Comment: It was a typo in the question, not in the actual code. The problem still exists as usual. There is no variable obj, only sObj.

Comment: @Laurens this isn't the answer. As I said in response to the comment it was not a typo.